# Skip RuntimeError inside numpy.apply_along_axis

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling

I have a function fitting several x,y arrays through the following algorithm:

```
def f(func, data, init):
   import scipy.optimize as opt
   from numpy import apply_along_axis

   fit = lambda d: opt.curve_fit(func, d[:cut], d[cut:], p0=[init, init], maxfev=100)[0]

   return apply_along_axis(fit, 1, data)
```

So, I apply the fitting to each 1st-axis of data (shape=(50000,6)), however, suddenly, there are problematic fitting in some rows halting the numpy.apply_along_axis and returning RuntimeError. Since I don't care about wrong fits, I would like to skip them.

Therefore, is it possible to disable those RuntimeError's inside the apply_along_axis function?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply handle the exception and return 0 when a `RuntimeError` happens.

**Edit**: The handling is now in the `fit` condition.

```
def fit(d):
    try:
        return opt.curve_fit(func, d[:cut], d[cut:], p0=[init, init], maxfev=100)[0]
    else:
        return 0
```

However, I don't know if returning 0 is the best thing to do. `apply_along_axis` expect the function to return either an array or a scalar. It is up to you to define what you want to return. `curve_fit` sends the reason of the runtime error when raising it. It should help you know what is the best thing to do, and maybe even how to prevent the exception in the first place. You might want to post it here to help us see what's the problem.

You can find more informations about exception handling here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

By the way, you have the greatest avatar.

Comment: This is a good idea, but the exception handling should be done inside the `fit` function, to skip only some rows and not the entire array.

Comment: Thanks, @Fury, adventure time is the greatest animation series nowadays. Yes, moarningsun is right, I need to Handle Exception inside curve_fit or apply_along_axis. I just want to skip the problematic fitting.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a new `fit` function. As stated, I don't know if returning 0 is the best thing to do, but since `apply_along_axis` expect something, you can't just return `None`.